# logread in OPENWRT

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, openwrt

Hi I want to read all the requests for network that are connected to my OPENWRT installed router now I am getting all the logs of the system with the help of

```
logread -e ': query'
```

The following in the output

```
Mon Sep 11 07:44:20 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq[1377]: query[A] e8037.g.akamaiedge.net from 192.168.150.201
Mon Sep 11 07:44:20 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq[1377]: query[AAAA] e8037.g.akamaiedge.net from 192.168.150.201
Mon Sep 11 07:44:20 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq[1377]: query[A] qa.sockets.stackexchange.com from 192.168.150.201
Mon Sep 11 07:44:29 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq[1377]: query[A] osfsr.lenovomm.com from fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
```

But the actual problem is **logread** is having lot of junk data which I wont be using. So I have to go through the above filtering.

Is there any place where I can tell OPENWRT to log only the above filterd data into **logread** file. Or redirect the above code to any **.txt** files of my router (Every 30 minutes I will run a cron job to push the .txt code to the server to make sure that router wont get crashed. Anyways its having 1.3 Mb space left.)

**NOTE** - I have tried out with ipvoxy, ulogd and other couple of things but at last I am going with the above method to directly read from the logs.

Comment: What I have done is telling `syslog` to send all the logs to another machine.

Answer (score 4):

> Or redirect the above code to any .txt files of my router (Every 30 minutes I will run a cron job to push the .txt code to the server to make sure that router wont get crashed. Anyways its having 1.3 Mb space left.)

You can use a redirect.

```
logread -f | grep ': query' > /path/to/file.txt
```

Your cron job can then copy the file and empty it as needed.

You could also alter the syslogd config file so that your router pushes its logs to a syslog server, which you can then filter with syslogd on your server to only save dnsmasq tagged entries, as well as filter.

Comment: Syslog can be directed to log to another machine. An openWRT server usually does not have space for extensive logging.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes... thats what the last paragraph says.